# How To merge two tables in vb.net as full outer join in sql and withou database

Tags: vb.net

I have two Data tables `Table A` and `Table B`

Both having some data.

I want to do merge both data table into single table in vb.net, not in back end, just only front end that's vb.net.

```
 Table A
---------------------------
ID        Name            Balance
1         neha             10
2         khushi           20
3         kaffi            40
4         manju            50


 Table B
  ------------------------------

 ID        Address          Balance
  1         jind               10
  2        kaithal             20
  5        usa                 20
  6        gurgaon             20
  7        Dalhousie           20
 Table C =>TableA+TableB(As Outer Join)
```

result

---

```
ID      Name            Address      Balance
1       neha             jind         10+10=20
2       khushi           kaithal      20+20=40
3       kaffi                         40
4       manju                         50
5                        usa          20
6                        gurgaon      20
7                        dalhousie    20
```

Comment: Would you be joining on ID?  You could just create a view that joins the two tables and then that view can be queried however you like as if it were an actual table.  Or a stored procedure that returns the two tables joined as a single table.

Comment: there is stored procedure that return tables so i want to merge both table on the basis of id i already used data relation but not getting result what i want because it provide result as parent and child table but in that tables getting result dynamic i want data of both tables not single parent table

Comment: What you are showing above as your desired result is just a normal outer join.  I'm suggesting that you do the join in a view or stored procedure.

Comment: no i cant do because i am working on entity framework and every table comes from different database so procedure is dynamic depends on parent=>child relationship and it will go in n numbers. so i cant do it in back end i have to handle these in front end only because i dont know levels dere

Comment: Perhaps using LINQ to do something similar to what the asker of this question is trying to do is the best approach for you then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015284/vb-net-linq-left-outer-join-between-two-datatables-limit-to-one-row

Comment: its all about linq and i dont want to do as in back end i earlier told u what i want i asked u above and only from front end that's VB.NET

Comment: Ummm...LINQ is front-end...

Answer (score 0):

So as if you want to do it in vb.net only,i am just suggesting one of the traditional ways(dont ask me about performance issues).

First of all take the data from two tables into two datatables.then using two for loops lop through the datatable while checking the id.if id becomes same write all the data into another datatable.

Code Equivalent

```
dim da1,da2,da3 as datatable
dim introw as integer
''fill the datatables da1 and da2 with data from tableA and TableB

da3.columns.add("id")
da3.columns.add("name")
da3.columns.add("adress")
da3.columns.add("balance")

for intcount1=0 to da1.rows.count-1
  for intcount2=0 to da2.rows.count-1
   if da1.rows(intcount1).item("id")=da2.rows(intcount2).item("id") then 
       da3.addrows(1)
       da3.rows(introw).item(0)=da1.rows(introw).item(0)
       da3.rows(introw).item(1)=da1.rows(introw).item(1)
       da3.rows(introw).item(2)=da2.rows(introw).item(1)
       da3.rows(introw).item(3)=da1.rows(introw).item(2)+da1.rows(introw).item(2)
 end if
next 
next
```

please modify according to your logic.i dont know if this may help you,just tried to get you a light to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dim Joined = New DataTable
    Joined.Columns.AddRange({New DataColumn("ID"), New DataColumn("Name"), New DataColumn("Address"), New DataColumn("Balance")})

    Call (From t1 In TableA
          Join t2 In TableB On t1("ID") Equals t2("ID")
          Select Joined.Rows.Add(t1("ID"), t1("Name"), t2("Address"), CSng(t1("Balance")) + CSng(t2("Balance")))).ToList
```

Comment: above linq query throw error definition of method 'join' is not accessible in this context

Answer (score 0):

```
    ViewState("ParentRowsCount") = ds.Tables(ParentTable).Rows.Count
            ' Merge parent and child table
            ds.Tables(ParentTable).Merge(ds.Tables(ChildTable))
            ' create uniqueness through remove duplicate keys 
            Dim dtpartbl As DataTable = ds.Tables(ParentTable)
            dtpartbl = RemoveDuplicateRows(dtpartbl, "ID")
            ' In Merging make all values to be null
            Dim row12 As DataRow = ds.Tables(ParentTable).NewRow()
            For i As Integer = ViewState("ParentRowsCount") + 1 To ds.Tables(ParentTable).Rows.Count
                For n As Integer = 1 To ds.Tables(ParentTable).Columns.Count - 1
                    ds.Tables(ParentTable).Columns(n).AllowDBNull = True
                    ds.Tables(ParentTable).Rows(i - 1).Item(n) = 0
                Next
                ds.AcceptChanges()
            Next

            Dim DataMap As DataRelation = ds.Relations.Add("Master" & ItrationCount, ds.Tables(ParentTable).Columns("ID"), ds.Tables(ChildTable).Columns("ID"))
```